Altium designer-PCB design- Keep-out layer
I have a board and I want to reshape the board, I draw the keep out layer first as follows:

Then when I reshape the PCB, I see a thick green line around the board, but I expect to see a pink line (keep-out-layer), would you please let me know how can I fix this:


You have plane (negative copper) layer(s); the thickness of the green line is simply the design rule applied to those layers -- you're seeing the negative (removed) copper.

Hello Tim, thank you very much, how can I decrease the thickness? where in the design rule? thanks in advance

@Behnam why do you want to decrease the thickness? Copper too close to the board edge can cause problems. Would just making the plane layer not visible solve your problem?

@thank you for your message, yes, I just want to hide them

At bottom of the screen, find the offending layer(s), right-click, and select Hide.

Draw a boarder in the keep out layer. You can either select items from another layer to copy over or draw it. Usually its better to import a dxf for the board outline and then copy it to the keep out layer.

Hello, thanks for the comment, I did the same thing, the issue is the green line after reshaping the board, I want the green lines to be removed and i do not know how?
